# References for "Compactness Operator in set theory and topology" - why antispace is kind a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compact-operators

I find [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antispace) that

> Antispace is a kind of topological space

I try to find this little book (70p) to read online

> 1968, Evert Wattel, The Compactness Operator in Set Theory and Topology:
>   *There exists a natural one to one mapping from the class of antispaces onto itself […]*

I want to deep
Someone can help me to retrieve it?

Comment: What does "to deep" mean?

Comment: I want to study deeper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not heard about antispaces so far, but I googled a little and found

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183528866

http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1969__21_4_349_0.pdf

Comment: very interesting, thank you